# Would it be possible for shellcode to call non exported functions in a dll?

Tags: shellcode

It is just a question that came into mind today.
I know that you can use getprocaddress to get the location of exported functions at runtime..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918234/calling-a-non-exported-function-in-a-dll

Here someone suggested to search for a binary pattern.
Would there be any reason that this would not work when dealing with for example injected shellcode?

Or could you get a raw address at runtime of an exported function and knowing that calculate the offset to a non-exported function and call it? Also would this work with modern memory mitigations without triggering some violation?

Answer (score 1):

Not only can it be done, but calls can be made into the middle of functions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming

I believe it's even possible to call into the middle of multibyte instructions (on x86) which results in a completely different interpretation of those instructions.

So yeah.  There are tools for that.